# How can I plot the frequency spectrum of noise?

Tags: algorithm

I wish to plot the EMI noise generated by high frequency switching circuits in simulink. The spectrum scope shows a plot in dB vs frequency. I want to plot this in log frequency scale.

Comment: -1: no code provided; -1: no error message from that code.  What isn't working?  What tools are you having problems with?  Or, is this a plzsendtehcodez question?

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. Post what you have tried so far and we can help.

Comment: If I had votes, I'd vote to close.

Comment: I agree the question is vague and probably demanding, but I think/hope this is due to poor knowledge of the english language so I give him/her the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you have data containing Frequency -> dB and you want to plot it using the log of the frequency?

For example if you have the following:

```
Freq   dB
  63   70
 125   75
 250   71
 500   75
1000   65
2000   77
4000   79
8000   74
```

You want the log of the freq:

```
Freq   dB     Log(Freq)
  63   70     1.8
 125   75     2.1
 250   71     2.4
 500   75     2.7
1000   65     3.0
2000   77     3.3
4000   79     3.6
8000   74     3.9
```

And plot it in a graph:

```
80 |
 - |                           x
76 |                        x
 - |            x     x           x  
72 |
 - |         x     x
68 |
 - |                     x
64 |

     |----|----|----|----|----|----|
    1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0
```

If so, you can just take the data and convert each frequency to the log of the frequency.